# ASP.NET Web Api - Unified JSON Api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, json.net, asp.net-4.5

I'm Writing an Api using the new ASP.Net 4.5 Web Api.
My Api responses are very similar to [fourSquare's Api Response Messages](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/responses).
My api should always response with messages like this one:

```
{
    Meta:
    {
        Code: "401"
        ErrorDetails: "Not Authorized!"
    }
    Response: "The Api Response Object or Text'
}
```

The meaning is that I should **always** return Http Status Code of: **200 OK**
Any error indication will be located withing the "Meta" tag.
So, I've implemented a MediaFormatter for all Json Requests.
Looks like this:

```
 public class MyApiResponseFormatter : JsonMediaTypeFormatter
{
    public MyApiResponseFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }

    public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, System.IO.Stream writeStream, System.Net.Http.HttpContent content, System.Net.TransportContext transportContext)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            ApiResponse apiResponse = CreateApiResponse(type, value);

            using (StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(writeStream))
            {
                requestWriter.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(apiResponse, new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
                }));
            }
        });
    }

    private ApiResponse CreateApiResponse(Type type, object value)
    {
        #region Handle Errors
        Type exceptionType = null;
        ErrorDetails errorDetails = null;
        HttpStatusCode statusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        if (type == typeof(HttpError))
        {
            exceptionType = Type.GetType(((System.Web.Http.HttpError)value)["ExceptionType"].ToString());
            errorDetails = new ErrorDetails()
            {
                Message = ((System.Web.Http.HttpError)value)["ExceptionMessage"].ToString(),
                StackStace = ((System.Web.Http.HttpError)value)["StackTrace"].ToString()
            };

            // get the status code
            if (exceptionType == typeof(UnauthorizedAccessException))
            {
                statusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            }
            else
            {
                statusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            };
        }
        #endregion

        ApiResponse apiResponse = new ApiResponse()
        {
            Meta = new MetaData()
            {
                Code = (int)statusCode,
                ErrorType = exceptionType,
                ErrorDetails = errorDetails
            },

            Notifications = null,
            Response = type == typeof(HttpError) ? null : value
        };
        return apiResponse;
    }

    public override Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream readStream, System.Net.Http.HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
    {
        return base.ReadFromStreamAsync(type, readStream, content, formatterLogger);
    }
}
```

Everything seems to be fine except the fact that if an exception is raised, the status code on the Response is not 200 (it is 500 - internal server error)
So I've added this line of code that seems like a hack:
`HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;`

Something doesn't feel right in this solution.
Any experienced web api insights about how to implement such an Api will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: My question is why would you want to duplicate such a horribly bad practice.  HTTP headers are designed to return metadata.  Creating a new metadata mechanism inside the body is just reinventing SOAP.  Web API was designed to follow the HTTP spec to the letter.  You are going to be swimming upstream to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: I was trying to copy the best practice of one the most convenient APIs on the web - fourSquare's. they have a very nice post about it: [apiv2-woulda-coulda-shoulda](http://engineering.foursquare.com/2011/07/08/apiv2-woulda-coulda-shoulda/)

Comment: How convenient was it when the deprecated v1 of the api and replaced it with a new incompatible one?

Comment: web-api should always return an HttpResponse, as a consumer I shouldn't have to inspect an additional property to see if my OK response is actually an ok response. This violates the Richardson Maturity Model Level 2 HTTP Verbs [RMM Level 2 ref](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html#level2)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys.  I've adopted your advises and changed the entire response mechanism to the standard one.